# how to enable progress bar while loading custom listview in android

Tags: android

I need to maintain 3000 list items in listview(android) .But continue scrolling will make error. To manage this I plan to show progress dialog while loading the listview.

Please suggest me how to do it in android.

Comment: Have you not used async task before..?? You just need to show progress dialog in onPreExcute() and fetch the 3000 items in doInBackground() , and then finally dismiss() the dialog in onPost

Comment: Hi used Asynctask and the data is already available in my local db, but when scrolling 4 -5 times continually it cause error.

Comment: Apart from using LazyList for images you should use view holder..

Comment: It seems you were not managing the convert view and view holder to ensure view reusability

Comment: Before I done without view holder but after adding view holder also keep on scrolling makes ourOfMemory error. How to manage this.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lazylist for your problem here is [link](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList) check it. You can find your solution. You can use Async tasks but the whole 3000 items will be loaded at once. If you use LazyList then you will few items will be loaded first and when you scroll down more items will be added to your list.

Answer (score 0):

*ListView is itself a fabulous component available for the rendering the n munber of records.*
*There is recycling of the same view again and again so as to avoid memory leaks and efficient management.*

**You must use :
Lazy List for images and view holder must be managed efficiently for managing the re usability of views.**

**Recycling concept :**

Every time ListView needs to show a new row on screen, it will call the getView() method from its adapter. As you know, getView() takes three arguments arguments: the row position, a convertView, and the parent ViewGroup.

The convertView argument is essentially a “ScrapView” . It will have a non-null value when ListView is asking you recycle the row layout. So, when convertView is not null, you should simply update its contents instead of inflating a new row layout. The getView() code in your adapter would look a bit like:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);
    }

    TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
    text.setText("Position " + position);

    return convertView;
}
```

View Holder pattern
Finding an inner view inside an inflated layout is among the most common operations in Android. This is usually done through a View method called findViewById(). This method will recursively go through the view tree looking for a child with a given IDcode. Using findViewById() on static UI layouts is totally fine but, as you’ve seen, ListView calls the adapter’s getView() very frequently when scrolling. findViewById() might perceivably hit scrolling performance in ListViews—especially if your row layout is non-trivial.

The View Holder pattern is about reducing the number of findViewById() calls in the adapter’s getView(). In practice, the View Holder is a lightweight inner class that holds direct references to all inner views from a row. You store it as a tag in the row’s view after inflating it. This way you’ll only have to use findViewById() when you first create the layout. Here’s the previous code sample with View Holder pattern applied:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.textView01 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.textView01.setText("Position " + position);

    return convertView;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView textView01;
}
```